# Is there open scientific analysis of the proposed discharge of water from Fukushima?

Tags: environmental-protection

Today in the news Japan has announced it will discharge water from Fukushima.
All news sites I have looked at covering this give very little detail, only that about 1.4M Tonnes of water will be discharged, that it contains tritium, and that various groups and countries protest.
e.g https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2021/apr/13/fukushima-japan-to-start-dumping-contaminated-water-pacific-ocean

The IAEA themselves support the discharge, but their latest press release also contains no real data.
https://www.iaea.org/newscenter/pressreleases/iaea-ready-to-support-japan-on-fukushima-water-disposal-director-general-grossi-says
In the video attached there, they say the IAEA will help with the implementation of a plan, without being clear if the plan exists.

I assume a thorough analysis will include all radio nucleides in the water, a discharge plan that keeps all of these within certain limits in the sea water. I expect it to address issue like: What is initial discharge process? What monitoring is done? How will this feedback into the discharge process? Must discharge follow certain tidal flows? Might it be halted under storm conditions, or take into account seasonal variation in sea-life?

Has such an analysis been published?

Comment: this might help you find information about this https://safecast.org/2018/06/part-1-radioactive-water-at-fukushima-daiichi-what-should-be-done/ it is an old article but i think it is relevant still.if you search for fukushima+tritium you will find a lot of information.

Comment: There's a commentary there: https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2021/04/japan-plans-release-fukushima-s-contaminated-water-ocean.